# How to prevent fatal errors from bad input into d2i_X509_REQ_bio in Swift with OpenSSL

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, openssl

Context:

I've got the following code that loads data into a BIO and then gets an X509Req with it:

```
    let reqBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
    let result = BIO_write(reqBIO, (reqData as NSData).bytes, Int32(reqData.count))
    let x509ReqContainer: UnsafeMutablePointer<X509_REQ> = d2i_X509_REQ_bio(reqBIO, nil)
    BIO_free(reqBIO)
```

This code works great when the input is a base64 Encoded DER like it expects. If I pass a base64Encoded garbage string however, it blows up, and ugly, throwing a fatal Error.

So my questions are:

1. Is there some method in OpenSSL I can call that will allow me to determine if the BIO is safe to send to the d2i function so I can fail gracefully in those cases
2. Is there any way to catch a fatalError in swift? (I'm guessing no)
3. Is there some other way to validate that my base64 string contains a CSR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short version:* `d2i_X509_REQ_bio()` does not “throw an error” on invalid input. It simply returns a null pointer. What crashes is that you (perhaps inadvertently) force-unwrap an optional in Swift.

*Longer version:* The C function

```
X509_REQ *d2i_X509_REQ_bio(BIO *bp, X509_REQ **x);
```

returns a null pointer on invalid input. This C function is mapped to Swift as

```
func d2i_X509_REQ_bio(...) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<X509_REQ>!
```

with an “implicitly unwrapped optional” (IUO) as the return type, and a null pointer is represented as `nil`. An IUO is almost equivalent to a “normal” (strong) optional, with the only difference that it is force-unwrapped if required by the type checker. And that is what happens at the assignment

```
let x509ReqContainer: UnsafeMutablePointer<X509_REQ> = d2i_X509_REQ_bio(reqBIO, nil)
```

because the variable is declared as *non-optional.* If the C function returns a null pointer because of invalid input then the Swift `Optional.nil` is unwrapped, and the program is terminated with a runtime error.

*Solution:* Use optional binding with `if let` (or `guard let`) and let the compiler infer the type automatically:

```
if let x509ReqContainer = d2i_X509_REQ_bio(reqBIO, nil) {
    // success ...
} else {
    // failed ...
}
```

*Remark:* You can write  `Data` to the BIO with

```
let result = reqData.withUnsafeBytes {
    BIO_write(reqBIO, $0.baseAddress, Int32($0.count))
}
```

instead of casting it to `NSData`.

Comment: Fantastic well written explanation. I ended up finding the same thing on my own this afternoon, and you broke down the science as why. I was able to use the guard protection statements, and it all works great. By that same token, I technically could use a TYPE? as the variable being assigned too, and that would prevent the issue too.

Comment: Follow up question, related. What is the primary purpose of using an IUO in the first place? What are the normal use cases to them since in this case it was dangerous

Comment: @Unome: *You* should avoid them if possible. They are sometimes needed for properties which cannot be initialized immediately, but are known to be initialized before used. A typical example are *outlets* (IBOutlet): they are not initialized in your code but when (for example) a view controller is loaded from a storyboard. – *Here* the Swift importer maps the C pointers to IUOs as a trade-off, because the C declarations have no [nullability annotations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/designating_nullability_in_objective-c_apis).